# Expand Table view cell and collapse

Tags: swift, uitableview

[Refer this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qCpZ.png)

In my table cell there is an image indicating arrow up symbol if cell is expanded and arrow down image is cell is collapsed.

If I tap on CellA, it expands and arrow_icon changes. But, when I tap on CellB, CellA collapsed and arrow_Icon not changing..

Comment: And do you have code that is used for this?

Comment: Try this Library it will solve your purpose https://github.com/gabrielPeart/RRNCollapsableSectionTableView